# Como trocar o fundo do JOptionPane com uma imagem?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Tem como usar essa "`ImageIcon`" como fundo de um `JOptionPane`?

Segue o código que tentei:

```
public static void main(String args []){

  UIManager UI = new UIManager();
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Imagens/Imagem.jpg"); //Declara Icon como Imagem

  UI.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));
  UI.put("OptionPane.messageForeground", Color.white);
  UI.put("OptionPane.background", Color.black);  
  UI.put("Panel.background", Color.black);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio não ser possível. `JOptionPane` já é uma implementação básica de uma janela modal de avisos. Se quer algo mais personalizado, o melhor caminho é construir seu próprio componente.

Alterar pelas definições do [look and feel(LAF)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) é bem mais complexo, pois além de só alterar quando o LAF [nimbus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) estiver aplicado, se mudar para outro LAF, todas essas mudanças serão ignoradas. Como alternativa a isso, construí esse [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), que funciona como um `JOptionpane` plano mas customizável, trechos relevantes estão comentados:

```
class JOptionBackgroundPane extends JDialog {

    BufferedImage imgBackground;
    JLabel label;

    public JOptionBackgroundPane(BufferedImage imgBackgound, String message) {
        this.imgBackground = imgBackgound;
        makeUI(message);
    }

    private void makeUI(String message) {

        JPanel backgroundPane = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponents(g);
                //desenha a imagem no componente como fundo
                g.drawImage(imgBackground, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        label = new JLabel(message);

        //mude para cor de primeiro plano que quiser
        label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //mude para o formato de fonte que quiser
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        JButton btn = new JButton("OK");

        btn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            dispose();
        });

        backgroundPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(backgroundPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //workaround para evitar que o label fique colado no topo
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, Math.round(getPreferredSize().height*0.1f))));
        backgroundPane.add(label);
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        backgroundPane.add(btn);
        //workaround para evitar que o label fique colado na parte de baixo
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, Math.round(getPreferredSize().height*0.1f))));

        setModal(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setContentPane(backgroundPane);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        //força o container a ter sempre o mesmo tamanho da imagem
        return new Dimension(imgBackground.getWidth(), imgBackground.getHeight());
    }
}
```

para usar, basta passar uma imagem através de um `BufferredImage`, mais ou menos assim:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SuaClasse.class.getResource("path da imagem"));

JOptionBackgroundPane pane = new JOptionBackgroundPane(image, "mensagem");
pane.setVisible(true);
```

---

Você pode ver funcionando através do exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JOptionPaneBackground {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(
                new URL("https://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a64/thumb/background-wallpapers-blue-opera-light-images.jpg"));

        JOptionBackgroundPane pane = new JOptionBackgroundPane(image, "Teste");
        pane.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class JOptionBackgroundPane extends JDialog {

    BufferedImage imgBackground;
    JLabel label;

    public JOptionBackgroundPane(BufferedImage imgBackgound, String message) {
        this.imgBackground = imgBackgound;
        makeUI(message);
    }

    private void makeUI(String message) {

        JPanel backgroundPane = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponents(g);
                //desenha a imagem no componente como fundo
                g.drawImage(imgBackground, 0, 0, this);
            }
        };

        label = new JLabel(message);

        //mude para cor de primeiro plano que quiser
        label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        //mude para o formato de fonte que quiser
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));

        label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        JButton btn = new JButton("OK");

        btn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            dispose();
        });

        backgroundPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(backgroundPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //workaround para evitar que o label fique colado no topo
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, Math.round(getPreferredSize().height*0.1f))));
        backgroundPane.add(label);
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        backgroundPane.add(btn);
        //workaround para evitar que o label fique colado na parte de baixo
        backgroundPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, Math.round(getPreferredSize().height*0.1f))));

        setModal(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setContentPane(backgroundPane);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        //força o container a ter sempre o mesmo tamanho da imagem
        return new Dimension(imgBackground.getWidth(), imgBackground.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado.. realmente estava com essa duvida se era possivel ou não por ser algo mais simples..

Comment: @RafaelReis chegou a testar a classe que fiz? Ela faz algo semelhante ao que você queria fazer.

Comment: Acabei testando sim, mudei algumas coisinhas mas a base funciona bem parecido com o que eu queria

Comment: @RafaelReis se a resposta lhe serviu, você pode aceita-la clicando no `v`, assim ela pode servir de referencia para outros que tiverem um problema semelhante ao seu.