# Como colocar ícone nos botões do JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Como eu faço para colocar um ícone nos Botões "Continuar" e "Cancelar" que aparecem na janela do `JOptionPane`?

O caso está representado abaixo:

```
 public void metodo(){    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    JLabel label = new JLabel("qualquer texto");
                    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(20);
                    panel.add(label);
                    panel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                    panel.add(pass);
                    String[] options = new String[]{"Continuar", "Cancelar"};
                    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Aviso",
                            JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                            null, options, options[1]);
    }
```

Se fosse um botão comum era bem simples era só fazer assim:

```
JButon.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/logo-mini.png"))); //
```

Mas não sei como fazer isto com os componentes do `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar uma versão personalizada de uma janela modal(utilizar a classe [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) é uma opção viável para isso). [Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199687/28595)  há um exemplo de uma janela modal personalizada, basta criar uma semelhante, adicionar seus botoes personalizados conforme quiser. [**Na documentação**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) também há alguns exemplos e demais orientações.

Vale lembrar que, por se tratar de uma janela totalmente personalizada, você precisará implementar listener para os botões também, conforme a opção selecionada pelo usuário.

**[Já esta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13921883/5524514)** demonstra que é possível passar um array de botoes com seus respectivos ícones para o método [`showOptionDialog()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-):

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( parent, question, title,
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,
   new Component[]{ new JButton("OK", myIcon), 
                    new JButton("cancel", myOtherIcon) 
                  },null
 );
```

Comment: Acho que ele quer botar ícones nos botões, e não o ícone da telinha.

Comment: @VictorStafusa suponho que seja duplicata dessa outra aqui entao, neste caso, pois ele precisa criar uma versão personalizada do JOptionPane concorda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199687/28595

Comment: Então é isso que  ele disse aqui no comentário. Preciso alterar o ícone do Botão

Comment: Muito obrigado consegui resolver graças a você.

Comment: @ViniciusSilva qual das formas utilizou? Não pude testar o exemplo da resposta porque estou sem IDE no momento.

Comment: Este ultimo, só estava  faltando os 2  parâmetros que passei.

Comment: @VictorStafusa pq apagou? A resposta sua explorando a reescrita da classe ficou ótima. Já tava até dando vote nela quando recebi um erro.

Comment: @Articuno Ok, restaurei ela. É que sei lá, fiquei com a impressão de estar reinventando a roda quadrada.

Comment: A solução funcionou bem para adicionar os ícones , no entanto estes botões não fecham o JOptionPane por default . Tem algum método que faz isto para eu poder  chamar no Action do Jbutton? tipo um .dispose() ??

Comment: @ViniciusSilva entao voce precisa fazer a primeira dica, implementr sua propria tela dialogo, confome expliquei no começo da resposta, ou pode implementar a soluçao dada pelo victor na outra resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Fuçando nos detalhes internos das classes `javax.swing.JOptionPane` e `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI`, consegui fazer com isso:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author Victor Stafusa
 */
public class TesteJOptionPane {
    private static final Constructor<?> BUTTON_CONSTRUCTOR;
    private static final IntFunction<Object[]> BUTTON_ARRAY_CONSTRUCTOR;

    static {
        Class<?> buttonClass;
        try {
            buttonClass = Class.forName("javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI$ButtonFactory");
            BUTTON_CONSTRUCTOR = buttonClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, int.class, Icon.class, int.class);
            BUTTON_CONSTRUCTOR.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
            throw new NoClassDefFoundError(x.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
        BUTTON_ARRAY_CONSTRUCTOR = n -> (Object[]) Array.newInstance(buttonClass, n);
    }

    private static Icon imagem1() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                image.setRGB(i, j, 0xFF336699);
            }
        }
        return new ImageIcon(image);
    }

    private static Icon imagem2() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                image.setRGB(i, j, 0xFF993366);
            }
        }
        return new ImageIcon(image);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        AtomicReference<String> x = new AtomicReference<>();
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            String resposta = escolherOpcao(
                    "Mensagem de texto",
                    "Aviso",
                    "Cancelar",
                    new Opcao("Continuar", imagem1()),
                    new Opcao("Cancelar", imagem2()));
            x.set(resposta);
        });
        System.out.println(x.get());
    }

    public static final class Opcao {
        private final String texto;
        private final Icon imagem;
        private final Object buttonFactory;

        public Opcao(String texto, Icon imagem) {
            this.texto = texto;
            this.imagem = imagem;
            try {
                this.buttonFactory = BUTTON_CONSTRUCTOR.newInstance(texto, 0, imagem, -1);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException x) {
                throw new AssertionError(x);
            }
        }

        public String getTexto() {
            return texto;
        }

        public Icon getImagem() {
            return imagem;
        }

        public Object getButton() {
            return buttonFactory;
        }
    }

    public static String escolherOpcao(String message, String title, String defaultOption, Opcao... options) {
        String[] nomes = Stream.of(options).map(Opcao::getTexto).toArray(String[]::new);
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(
                message,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                null,
                nomes,
                defaultOption);
        pane.setOptions(Stream.of(options).map(Opcao::getButton).toArray(BUTTON_ARRAY_CONSTRUCTOR));
        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, title);
        dialog.show();
        Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();
        dialog.dispose();
        return Stream.of(options).filter(o -> o.getButton() == selectedValue).findFirst().map(Opcao::getTexto).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Eis o resultado:

[image: JOptionPane]

Esse código é complicado, mas vou explicar:

- Os métodos `imagem1()` e `imagem2()` são os responsáveis por criar os ícones. Um deles faz o ícone azul e o outro o ícone vermelho.
- A classe `JOptionPane` delega para `OptionPaneUI` a criação dos botões. No entanto `OptionPaneUI` é uma classe abstrata, e a subclasse concreta usada é `BasicOptionPaneUI`.
- [A classe `BasicOptionPaneUI` chama o método `getOptions()` de `JOptionPane`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.java#748) para decidir se deve criar os botões. Os botões são criados por meio da classe interna privada `ButtonFactory`, que aceita ícones.
- Assim sendo, a solução consiste em injetar instâncias de `ButtonFactory` dentro do `JOptionPane`. Como essa classe é privada, eu a instancio por meio de reflection.
- A classe `Opcao` corresponde aos botões que serão passados. Cada um com um nome e um ícone.
- O método `escolherOpcao(String, String, String, Opcao...)` é usado para exibir a caixa de mensagem. Os parâmetros são: a mensagem da janela, o título, a opção padrão e os botões das opções escolhidas.
- O método `escolherOpcao` retorna o texto do botão selecionado ou `null` se e usuário clicar no [image: ícone x].